# Selecting over a with clause that contains union all

Tags: sql, clickhouse, with-statement, union-all

Assume that you have a student table in clickhouse.

The query is here:

```
select * from ( 
with a as (select id from student)
select id from a
union all
select id from a
)
```

I am getting table Default.a doesnt exist (unknown table).

If I remove the select part which is after the union all, then query is running properly.

I allready tried enable_global_with_statement=1 setting and it isnt working.

Same query is running on postgres or mysql as expected.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. The outer select * query isn't useful here, but I assume the problem stays if you remove that part? Otherwise try to workaround it by introducing a second CTE that just duplicates a and then in the first select id use a and in the second b.

Comment: I know it is useless. My actual query is much more complex. Query in my question only represents the error condition

Comment: Also, interestingly, the problem occurs when you add the outer select

Comment: Probably not, but does it help if you give an alias to the outer result? Thus select * from (...) x

Comment: I already tried this :(

Comment: Maybe report the problem on ClickHouse's Github? 
https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues

Comment: it's a limitation of the current `WITH` implementation https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/41426

Comment: I am getting this error not only on distributed/replicated tables but also mergetree or postgresql engine vs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break down your query:

```sql
with a as (select id from student) -- First element of the UNION ALL
select id from a
union all
select id from a -- Second element of the UNION ALL
)
```

So you actually have the following elements:

```sql
with a as (select id from student) -- First element of the UNION ALL
select id from a
```

and

```sql
select id from a -- Second element of the UNION ALL
```

You can see that the CTE (WITH statement) belongs to only first part of the query. That's why you get `table default.a doesnt exist` because it is not defined for the second part.

If you want to have a CTE that can be accessible by all queries then you have to define it on top of all queries like this:

```sql
WITH a AS
    (
        SELECT number
        FROM numbers(10)
    )
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT number
    FROM a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT number
    FROM a
)

Query id: 4330405d-a04b-423a-af47-618c62d09251

┌─number─┐
│      0 │
│      1 │
│      2 │
│      3 │
│      4 │
│      5 │
│      6 │
│      7 │
│      8 │
│      9 │
└────────┘
┌─number─┐
│      0 │
│      1 │
│      2 │
│      3 │
│      4 │
│      5 │
│      6 │
│      7 │
│      8 │
│      9 │
└────────┘
```

Comment: It is an easy workaround for me. Thanks a lot.